# What is the format of my training data file?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I am new to Python and machine learning. I have this data [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxp_iuoQMgPVWjBGaWJSUUp2OXc/view?usp=sharing) on which I want to apply binary classification. But I am unable to guess its format and to load it in Python. Can someone help me out here?

In the dataset first column is class, and there are 100 features. I am using pandas IO to load it, and tried `read_csv`, but it's not working! And also it's definitely not JSON. (And I have used only these formats till now, so pardon me in advance if it is some well known format!)

Comment: The file appears to be in a custom format. Pandas won't have any read methods that could read this particular format so you would have to write your own custom code to parse through the dataset.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr Okay! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [sklearn.datasets.load_svmlight_file](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_svmlight_file.html) to read the file.

Here's an example from the documentation link on how to use the method:

```
from sklearn.externals.joblib import Memory
from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file
mem = Memory("./mycache")

@mem.cache
def get_data():
    data = load_svmlight_file("mysvmlightfile")
    return data[0], data[1]

X, y = get_data()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a pure text file. By looking at the first row, it looks like a libsvm format.
See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61328/libsvm-data-format) for a reference.